# How to connect to TeamViewer instance (on Windows XP) without installing it on my machine?

Tags: teamviewer

I would like to use any open source client. Would that work?

Comment: Which OS do you use on your system?

Comment: well ubuntu, i was hoping that it uses  VNC or other open standard and i can use a vnc client to connect ot the teamweaver instance on the xp

Comment: It's not an open system. You can run it like written below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamViewer is proprietary. But there is a client, which doesn't need to be installed: [TeamViewer Quicksupport](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx)